# Cglib Enhancer of HashMap on Google App Engine throws a Class Not Found Exception

Tags: java, google-app-engine, cglib

I am using cglib to enhance a HashMap so I can intercept method calls on the HashMap.

It works fine on my local computer, and when I run as a google web application within eclipse. Once deployed on the server, however, I am getting an exception "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: [Ljava/util/HashMap$Entry;"

The line of code that throws the exception is:

```
Enhancer.create(HashMap.class, new SomeInterceptor());
```

I am using the latest plugin for eclipse (3.7). I am using cglib version 2.2 (cglib-nodep-2.2.jar)

EDIT:
This is interesting: If I create a class that extends from HashMap, then I can enhance that class without any issues. For example, the following code works:

```
public class MyHashMap extends HashMap {
}
Enhancer.create(MyHashMap.class, new SomeInterceptor());
```

And Enhancer works for TreeMap, HashSet, and TreeSet
:ENDEDIT

The stack trace is:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: [Ljava/util/HashMap$Entry;
at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-02796318ce7d3a7b(Request.java)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2444)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:229)
at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.getCallbacksSetter(Enhancer.java:630)
at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.setCallbacksHelper(Enhancer.java:618)
at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.setThreadCallbacks(Enhancer.java:612)
at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createUsingReflection(Enhancer.java:634)
at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.firstInstance(Enhancer.java:538)
at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:225)
at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:377)
at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.create(Enhancer.java:285)
at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.create(Enhancer.java:663)
at com.enhancetest.EnhanceTestServlet.doGet(EnhanceTestServlet.java:30)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:449)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:455)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:695)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:333)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:325)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:453)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.util.HashMap$Entry
    ... 35 more

Comment: Perhaps it is not the problem but, check the jars that you included in your war lib.. are there any duplicate packages/classes/jars ?

Comment: Just checked, there are no duplicates. The jars are the ones included by default. I added only cglib-nodep-2.2.jar

Comment: TIP: switch one of your question tag with the official google-app-engine.. much more GAE experts can help you out ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps I'm missing something, if it is I'm sorry, but from a quick search I'found this: http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/cglib/cglib/2.2

It seems that GAE has only a `Partial support` to cglib... could this be the source of this issue?
Furthermore in the official GAE docs for supported Java libraries http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/WillItPlayInJava

CGLIB is not even mentioned.

EDIT:
BTW, I'm assuming that you are importing java.util.HashMap... check you did not import other implementation (like "com.google.gwt.dev.util.collect.HashMap")... somtimes this kind of mistake happens for nothing!

Comment: While I don't fully understand what part of cglib only partially supports GAE, I expected it to work for white listed classes. If I use cglib to enhance a class that I created, there is no problem: cglib enhances the class properly and I can intercept method calls. I am trying to enhance HashMap, which is on GAE's white list, so I would expect that to work too. http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist.html

There is also a mapreduce project for GAE that uses cglib. http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/source/browse/trunk/java/test_lib/cglib-nodep-2.2.jar?r=170

Comment: I have no doubt that HashMap is supported however it could be that this Map Reduce code is using only some feature which are supported... It is really hard to say

Comment: That's a good point, map reduce may not be using the enhancer. However, the enhancer works for classes that I've created. It also works for HashSet, TreeSet, and TreeMap. So it seems to me that this is compatible with GAE. I don't understand why it does not work for HashMap.

Comment: Yes, checked, and I am using java.tuil.HashMap. I also added an edit to my original comment - it works if I create a class that extends from HashMap and use that in the enhancer.